# Is there a better way to Display all entries in a DbContext by non-primary key?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Using .net core 3.0 - I've built a web API that let's user generate things on the Server. We'll call that an item.

```cs
    public class Item
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string StringId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double ImportantValue { get; set; }

    }
```

I want the user to access that Item, that will now sit in my DB, by StringId.

This is what I have:

```cs
        // GET: api/Item/foo123foo123
        [HttpGet("{stringId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<Item>>> GetItem(string stringId)
        {
            var Item = await _context.Items.Where(x => x.StringId == stringId).ToListAsync();

            if (Item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Item;
        }
```

For some reason the above only ever displays entries where StringId is null. I am making sure I actually have values in there, and that they properly match the request. Why? I've been sitting staring at this for a good hour now.

Comment: Are your strings null or empty?

Comment: _For some reason the above only ever displays entries where StringId is null_ - because `stringId` argument is a `null`, you need to check that `stringId` parameter "pickup" value correctly  from the url